# When emptying a tag, do the event-attached-buttons inside get garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having a code like this, I'm wondering if I ran this function a second time, which scenario will happen:

1. When emptying the #deals tag, all `btn` inside will get wiped as well despite the event on them and life is good.
2. I have to unsubscribe from those `btn` first, otherwise emptying the `#deals` tag leads to a memory leak?
3. List item

Code:

```
function test(){
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');  
    $(row).find('#deals').empty();

    $(result).find('#tab li a').each(function() {               
      var btn = $('<a/>', {class: 'btn', href: '#'});

      $(row).find('#deals').append(btn);

      btn.click(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          ...
         });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to unsuscribe :

> To avoid memory leaks, jQuery removes other constructs such as data
>   and event handlers from the child elements before removing the
>   elements themselves.

(from [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/empty/))

Answer (score 3):

No memory leak.

As you can see in [jQuery source](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.fn.empty), it takes care of cleaning everything up.

Comment: +1 for you for the link... I didn't knew this tool and I'm always using ctrl+f to browse the code...

Comment: @dystroy heh :) It has a successor though afaik, can't find it anymore. Also, it doesn't have all the methods. Github's source is sometimes better.